# How can I use a 'Global' class object?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, ide

I created a class inside the sketch file(not in another file) and init it as object before setup() and loop() as a global object, after I change some parameters inside the object in setup() , I found in loop() the parameters in the global object remain unchanged.
Here is the pseudocode code to describe my question:

```
//all of the code below are in the same ino file.
class Animal{
public:
  bool alive = false; 
  Animal (bool liveStatus){
    alive = liveStatus;
  }
}

Animal dog(false);
Animal cat(false);
Animal lion(false);
Animal animalArray(dog,cat,lion);




void setup(){

  for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    Animal current_animal = animalArray[i];
    current_animal.alive = true;
  }
  //here when I print each animal's alive flag is 'true'
}

void loop(){
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
         // here the alive flag of each animal is still false  , they should be all true!!
  }

}
```

It looks like after I quit setup() somehow every change of the global object inside the setup are all gone .

Thanks for helping me ..

Comment: I can't replicate this error. Can you post the whole code you were uploading before with the print statements and everything?

Comment: Hi BreetAm , the original code is relative complex and long(about 600 lines ) ,post to here won't be a good idea .. is that kind of codes works for you ?

Comment: Its great that you've tried to keep the example minimal, but in this case you also seem to have removed the source of your problem. Maybe you can pair down you code while constantly testing for the error and seeing how small you can make it without causing dog's value to reset?

Comment: Thanks BrettAM, I am currently doing more test on it , I will push a better example tomorrow and notify you :)

Comment: Hi BrettAM, sorry I didn't mentioned that I use array in my code . I've edited the example could you check it out please? :) Thanks...

Comment: I still don't have any problems, but this code is pretty far from compiling and the minimal changes I made to get it to compile could be different from your implementation. You should test these on your own first.

Comment: Hi BrettAM thanks for your kind help! I've reedited the example could you post your answer down then I could approve it for you and helping more people ,thanks! :DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that `Animal current_animal = animalArray[i];` is making a whole new Animal object that starts as a copy of `animalArray[i];`, but after that the two are no longer associated. Then when you call `current_animal.alive = true;`, you are not actually changing the animal in `animalArray[i]` anymore.

The simplest way to fix this is to make `current_animal` a reference to the object you pick out of the array, although a pointer would work the same way. With this code:

```
Animal& current_animal = animalArray[i];
current_animal.alive = true;
```

`current_animal` becomes a reference to `animalArray[i]`, instead of a copy. Then operating on `current_animal` changes the same data that is stored in `animalArray[i]` like you intend.

Comment: Thanks BrettAM for your kindness help , this solution saved my day .This problem should be very common on C or C++ languages which involve with pointer stuff  , such a shame I just forgot it even I was a computer science student ..  Thank you!